# How to use soft assertion in cucumber selenium framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, cucumber, assertion

Trying to setup automation framework in my project. I want to continue test run execution even the assertion gets fail in cucumber selenium framework. I tried using soft assertion but not sure how to implement in step definition methods.Kindly help me

```java
for (WebElement statNumber : stats) {
    String text = statNumber.getText();
    System.out.println(text);

    if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("£12.23%")) {
        condition = true;
        Reporter.addStepLog("First Stats grid value is £12.23%");
    } else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("45.45%")) {
        condition = true;
        Reporter.addStepLog("First Stats grid value is 45.45%");
    } else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("£1.75m")) {
        condition = true;
        Reporter.addStepLog("First Stats grid value is £1.75m");
    } else if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("2.2 Pound")) {
        condition = true;
        Reporter.addStepLog("First Stats grid value is 2.2 Pound");
    } else {
        softAssert.assertTrue(condition, text);
    }
}
```